# Prefer matching search term in beginning of search result rather than in the end using elasticsearch

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

I have a query that I can't quite get to return the most relevant answer.

If I search for 'herp' the result is

- fu herp
- herp derp
- bar herp
- herp aa

preferably I would like this order

- herp aa
- herp derp
- bar herp
- fu herp

So the question I have, I guess is: How do I get terms in the beginning of a sequence of words get higher score than one appearing nearer the end?

the analyser I use look like this:

```
"analyzer":[
  "autocomplete":[
    "type":"custom",
    "tokenizer":"standard",
    "filter":[ 
      "standard",
      "lowercase",
      "stop",
      "edgeNGramAlpha" 
    ]
  ],
  "filter":[
    "edgeNGramAlpha":[
      "type":"edgeNGram",
      "min_gram":1,
      "max_gram":20
    ]
  ]
]
```

and the mapping looks like this (loots of field but alla look the same)

```
"name": [
  "type": "multi_field",
  "fields" : [
    "untouched": [
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    ],
    "name": [
      "type": "string"
    ],
    "autocomplete": [
      "analyzer":"${language}_autocomplete",
      "type":"string",
    ]
  ]
]
```

and the query look like this:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "herp",
          "fields": [
            "name^8",
            "name.autocomplete^4",
            "historic_name.autocomplete"
          ],
          "type": "cross_fields",
          "operator": "AND",
          "analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to  provide an additional boost for terms at the beginning of the field using [span first](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-first-query.html)

Example :

```
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "disable_coord": true,
         "must": [
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "herp",
                  "fields": [
                     "name^8",
                     "name.autocomplete^4",
                     "historic_name.autocomplete"
                  ],
                  "analyzer": "standard"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {
               "span_first": {
                  "match": {
                     "span_term": {
                        "name": "herp"
                     }
                  },
                  "end": 1,
                  "boost": 1
               }
            },
            {
               "span_first": {
                  "match": {
                     "span_term": {
                        "historic_name": "herp"
                     }
                  },
                  "end": 1,
                  "boost": 1
               }
            }
         ],
         "minimum_number_should_match": 0
      }
   }
}
```